# Mars mips assembly , addi instead of Ori

Tags: assembly, mips

There is a question that I can't completely understand because of various answers I have saw , this is the instructions set :

```
lui $1,0xffffff00
ori $12,$1,0x0000ffff
sra $10,$12,0x00000010
and $8,$12,$10
```

The question is if you change the Ori instruction to addi , what will be the value of $8 ?

Comment: `addi` sign extends a 16 bit constant to 32 bits so if your assembler even accepts that form, `0x0000ffff` will be interpreted as `0xffffffff` aka `-1`. You can work out the rest yourself. Also, you can just try the code in a simulator/debugger.

Comment: I tried the code but when I write the lui command it says out of range.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are many MIPS assemblers, and that the assemblers vary, so you have to know which one you're working with to understand what machine code you're actually getting (or if it will even accept that input).

Then from the machine code, we can go strictly by the MIPS specification, and know exactly what a code sequence will do.

However, the main difference on MIPS for `addi` vs. `ori` — beyond the "add" vs. "or" part — is that though these are both I-Type instructions having 16-bit immediate, `addi` will employ ***sign extension*** to bring the 16-bit immediate to 32 bits for the addition, while `ori` will apply ***zero extension*** to bring the 16-bit immediate to 32 bits for the logical or operation.

Otherwise, since the low bits in `$1` are zeros anyway, the actual add vs. or doesn't make a difference: add vs. or are the same if there's no carry, and when adding to zero there's no carry.

Comment: I thought MIPS didn't have a carry flag though.

Comment: Whose talking about flags?  I'm merely speaking to addition.

Comment: "difference: add vs. or are the same if there's no carry, and when adding to zero there's no carry."

Comment: There's no mention of flags there.  Do you appreciate that addition involves propagation of carry from LSB to the higher bits, unlike OR, where there is no propagation of such?

Comment: Ok fair enough.

Comment: Case in point: MARS with "extended pseudo-instructions" enabled, will handle that `addi` by materializing `0x0000ffff` in a temp register and adding it with `add`.  So it actually adds the requested value, instead of truncating to a 16-bit immediate which will sign-extend to a different value.  Assemblers which do that should at least warn; others may error and not assemble at all, since an addi with that 32-bit value is not encodeable.